# Constraints on core libraries in sbt

Tags: java, scala, sbt

Is there any way to create constraints on core libraries in sbt?

for example:

I don't want anyone to use the Java Date Class, is there a way to create compilation errors/warnings for all direct imports to these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Wart Remover](https://github.com/typelevel/wartremover). Adapting the example from the readme, this should be something like (untested)

```
import org.brianmckenna.wartremover.{WartTraverser, WartUniverse}

object JavaDate extends WartTraverser {
  def apply(u: WartUniverse): u.Traverser = {
    import u.universe._

    val JavaDate: Type = typeOf[java.util.Date]
    val JavaCal: Type = typeOf[java.util.Calendar]
    new Traverser {
      override def traverse(tree: Tree) {
        tree.tpe match {
          case JavaDate =>
            u.error(tree.pos, "java.util.Date not allowed")
          case JavaCal =>
            u.error(tree.pos, "java.util.Calendar not allowed")
          case _ =>
        }
        super.traverse(tree)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anything, but you can import only the subclasses you want, you don't have to include just the top level one.